# Android - Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971. Searched in the following locations:

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

[I am having errors with my app, i just updated and got this errors, please help new to android development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQCjd.jpg)

Comment: did you add google() in your project gradle

Comment: please resync gradle also disable offline mode

Comment: Yes i include google() then this error came - > Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
  - butterknife-7.0.1.jar (com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1) ...i am using the latest version of android sdk

Comment: offline mode also if disable and now got this error - "Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see...@Ba

Answer (score 2):

In your **project** build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // add this
        jcenter()
    }
 }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // add this
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this error after adding google()  - "Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018"

Comment: just replace 'compile' with 'implementation'

Comment: You mean inside the build.gradle ? all compile with implementation ?

Comment: I did change all and it worked but then i got this -> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
  - butterknife-7.0.1.jar (com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1)
Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.